# RealmSwift: Casting Object.subscript AnyObject? to List<>

Tags: swift, realm

I’m writing a custom update method to allow control over how values are represented in Realm. The approach taken is to match incoming key: values (from JSON) against objects’ objectSchema.properties and convert the values accordingly. Everything is general-purpose with values stored using Object.subscript.

For to-one relations, where property type is .Object the system can recurse and create or update the appropriate nested object of type determined by Property.objectClassName.

For to-many relations, where property type is .Array we must modify a List of objects of type objectClassName. List however is a generic so that’s List< concrete type of objectClassName >.

As Object.subscript returns values of type AnyObject? we need to cast this into something that can be treated as a list irrespective of its contained type. How can this be achieved?

(I've replaced the example below to better illustrate the problem)
e.g.

```
typealias ValueDictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

func update(object: Object, values: ValueDictionary) {

    for property in object.objectSchema.properties {

        if let value = values[property.name] {

            var newValue: AnyObject?

            switch property.type {
                case .Object:
                    let objectType = NSClassFromString(
                        "mymodule" + property.objectClassName) as! Object.Type

                    newValue = relatedObjectWithType(objectType, 
                        values: value as! ValueDictionary)

                case .Array:
                    let objectType = NSClassFromString(
                        "mymodule" + property.objectClassName) as! Object.Type

                    newValue = listOfRelatedObjectsWithType(objectType, 
                        values: value as! [ValueDictionary])

                default:
                    // Convert primitive values, date strings, etc.
                    newValue = coerceValue(value, toPropertyType:property.type)
            }   
        }
    }

func relatedObjectWithClassName(type: Object.Type, values: ValueDictionary) -> Object {
    // To-one relations can be instantiated using Object.Type.
    var object = type.init()
    update(object, values)
    return object
}

// To-many relation are generic so there's no way to treat them dynamically.
func listOfRelatedObjectsWithType(type: Object.Type, values: [ValueDictionary]) -> List {
}
```

Comment: There error says it all. Change `List<AnyObject>` to `List<Object>`.

Comment: Unfortunately casting to List<Object> will SIGABRT. (Updated above).

Comment: All collections types in Realm (i.e. `List`, `Results` etc) subscribe to the `RealmCollectionType` protocol in order to indicate they behave like array objects. I haven't tested this, but have you tried `let list = relation as? RealmCollectionType`?

Comment: That's a great suggestion but results in the following: error: protocol 'RealmCollectionType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Comment: Hi Robin! Sorry for the delay! I asked some colleagues about this, and they were wondering what were the parameter types for the `updateList` method there (Specifically, what does it expect `list` to be?). Can you please add that to your sample code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

That's basically the problem. I need to write a method that will operate on a List<Unknown Derived Object Type>. The type of the list is determined at run-time.

Comment: Again, sorry for the delay Robin! Did you work out a solution in the end? I was giving this more thought, and I was wondering if this is the right way to go about mapping JSON data to Realm. When a `List` object is a property of a Realm `Object`, they are implicitly created and managed by the `Object`, and you simply append new objects to that one (i.e., there's not much point to creating new `List` instances). If that's the case, instead of trying to map your objects to a `List`, perhaps try creating a standard Swift array and then manually append those to the appropriate `List` property. :)